# Connect to SocketVoiceChannel (discord.NET)

Tags: c#, audio, discord.net

So I created a Bot a while ago, and the bot simply does commands in a text channel. So if I write "!clear this" I can delete all messages in a text channel on a server. Connection and everything to a text chat works fine. I designed a small Forms application so I now can see a simple console and connect to my servers by a press of a button. Now I want my bot to enter voice chats. I looked in the whole internet and found that you can connect simply with a SocketVoiceChannel

```
SocketVoiceChannel channel;
channel.ConnectAsync();
```

Now I don't know what to do with the channel. I looked at the definition of that class and it's base classes and never found a constructor. 
Older documentations suggested a `DiscordClient.FindServers("name", type)`, but with the DiscordSocketClient no such method exists.

What I got so far:

```
public void ConnectVoiceAsync()
{
    SocketVoiceChannel _voiceChannel = new SocketVoiceChannel();
    var connection = await _voiceChannel.ConnectAsync();
}
```

ConnectVoiceAsync() is called, when a Button is pressed. With my UI everything works fine. I can connect to the server and write/answer messages. Only the Audio connection does not work. The question is, how can I setup a SocketVoiceChannel? I know the name of the channel and the Id of the channel.

Comment: You don't construct your own entities you retrieve them from discord. So you can't do `new SocketVoiceChannel()`, you have to call `GetVoiceChannel()` on the guild.

Answer (score 0):

@Anu6is hint was the right way to go. In fact, the `GetVoiceChannel()` method did the trick just fine. I post the code I know have to help anyone with the same problem!

```
private DiscordSocketClient _client;
private CommandHandler _handler;
private SocketGuild _guild;
private SocketVoiceChannel _voiceChannel;
```

These are the key components for the discord bot. `_guild` and `_voiceChannel` get initialized in the method called by the button press. The commandHandler is my own class and is not provided by discord.Net but is not necessary for connecting to the voice channel anyway (in my case, if you wanted to connect by a command in discord like "!connect" it would be!). The methods to connect/ disconnect are as follows:

```
public async Task ConnectVoiceAsync()
        {
            _guild = _client.GetGuild(xyz);
            _voiceChannel = _guild.GetVoiceChannel(xyz); 
            var connection = await _voiceChannel.ConnectAsync();
            debugger.AddLogLine(0, "\n...\nConnection succeeded");
        }
public async Task ConnectVoiceAsync(ulong guildId, ulong channelId)
{
    try
    {
        _guild = _client.GetGuild(guildId);
        _voiceChannel = _guild.GetVoiceChannel(channelId);
        var connection = await _voiceChannel.ConnectAsync();
        debugger.AddLogLine(0, "\r\n...\r\n>>>Connection succeeded");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        debugger.AddLogLine(1, e.ToString());
    }

}

public async Task DisconnectVoiceAsync()
{
    try
    {
        if(_voiceChannel != null)
        {
            await _voiceChannel.DisconnectAsync();
            debugger.AddLogLine(0, "Bot Disconnected");
        }
        else
        {

            debugger.AddLogLine(1, "No Connection established!");
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        debugger.AddLogLine(1, e.ToString());
    }
}
```

I have two versions of the connect method because by checking a checkbox in the form one can connect to a preset voicechannel. If you do not wish to pass in the guild and server IDs by an interactive UI you can simply "hardcode" the IDs in ypur programm and use the first method. If you want the user to be able to connect to different servers flexibly you would use the overloaded method with the two parameters. 
If you do it like I did you have to be careful when you call the async Method. Here are the methods I have in the code behind of my Form!

```
private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (channel)
            {
                debugger.AddLogLine(0, "Awaiting Connection to VoiceChannel (Pos Kanal)!");

                await connectionManager.ConnectVoiceAsync();
            }
            else if(!channel && textBoxChanneld.Text == string.Empty && TextBoxGuildId.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                panelAdvancedConnect.Size = defaultSizeAdvanced;

            } else
            {
                ulong id1 = Convert.ToUInt64(TextBoxGuildId.Text);
                ulong id2 = Convert.ToUInt64(textBoxChanneld.Text);
                debugger.AddLogLine(0, "Trying to connect to ''" + id1.ToString() + " " + id2.ToString());
                await connectionManager.ConnectVoiceAsync(id1, id2);
            }


        }
```

Key takeway here is, that you declare your button methods with `async void`. Using  `async Task` will result in many errors. Debugger is an own class that adds a small console window to the application. 
[image: The Forms app]

Different panels such as the "connect to voice chat" and textboxes for the IDs "pop-up" on the fly to keep the design slim.